# Accessing sparse matrix created in MEX from MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, sparse-matrix, mex

I have created a sparse matrix in a MEX-file following the example shown in [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20060211061327/http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/Matlab/OldTechDocs/apiref/mxcreatesparse.html). Now how do I access this matrix from MATLAB as a whole.

```
#define NZMAX 4
#define ROWS  4
#define COLS  2

int            rows=ROWS, cols=COLS;
mxArray       *ptr_array; /* Pointer to created sparse array. */
static double  static_pr_data[NZMAX] = {5.8, 6.2, 5.9, 6.1};
static int     static_ir_data[NZMAX] = {0, 2, 1, 3};
static int     static_jc_data[COLS+1] = {0, 2, 4};
double        *start_of_pr;
int           *start_of_ir, *start_of_jc;
mxArray       *array_ptr;

/* Create a sparse array. */    
array_ptr = mxCreateSparse(rows, cols, NZMAX, mxREAL); 

/* Place pr data into the newly created sparse array. */ 
start_of_pr = (double *)mxGetPr(array_ptr); 
memcpy(start_of_pr, static_pr_data, NZMAX*sizeof(double));

/* Place ir data into the newly created sparse array. */ 
start_of_ir = (int *)mxGetIr(array_ptr); 
memcpy(start_of_ir, static_ir_data, NZMAX*sizeof(int));

/* Place jc data into the newly created sparse array. */ 
start_of_jc = (int *)mxGetJc(array_ptr); 
memcpy(start_of_jc, static_jc_data, NZMAX*sizeof(int));

/* ... Use the sparse array in some fashion. */
/* When finished with the mxArray, deallocate it. */
mxDestroyArray(array_ptr);
```

Also while storing the values in `static_pr_data`, `ic_data` and `jc_data` is it necessary to store the values in column major format? Is it possible to store in row major format (since it will speed up my calculation)?

Comment: Please post relevant code **here** rather than linking.

Comment: Will heed to ur advice Chris !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you link to, the last statement is

```
mxDestroyArray(array_ptr);
```

Instead of destroying the array, you need to return it as the output of your MEX-function. Your MEX-function C/C++ source code should have a function named `mexFunction` (the entry point for the MEX-function) that looks like this:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray * plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray * prhs[])
```

To return an output from the MEX-function, assign it into the `plhs` array, like this:

```
plhs[0] = array_ptr; // instead of mxDestroyArray(array_ptr);
```

Compile the code into a MEX-function (Let's call it `sparsetest`). Invoke it from MATLAB like this:

```
>> output = sparsetest;
```

Now `output` is a MATLAB variable containing the sparse matrix you created in your MEX-function.

As for storing the data in row-major format, that is not possible. MATLAB only handles column-major sparse matrices.

Comment: when i do output(1,1) or any index the value is always 0! The actual values i am not able to get. What is the problem? Am i accessing the values in  the wrong way?

Comment: I solved my problem , i had assumed that the values in ir data must start with index 1, but infact it should start with 0 indexing only ...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**A tip to get a matrix field from a matlab struct using `engGetVariable()`**

I have a struct with a field which is a matrix. In C++ the corresponding structure is a double** for instance. Trying to access the field with engGetVariable(engine,MyStruct.theField) fails. I use a temp variable to store the MyStruct.theField and then use engGetVariable(engine, tempVar), and code to get the matrix field from the struct looks like that

```
// Fetch struct field using a temp variable
std::string tempName = std::string(field_name) + "_temp";
std::string fetchField = tempName + " = " + std::string(struct_name) 
        + "." + std::string(field_name) + "; ";
matlabExecute(ep, fetchField);
mxArray *matlabArray = engGetVariable(ep, tempName.c_str());

// Get variable elements
const int count = mxGetNumberOfElements(matlabArray);
T *data = (T*) mxGetData(matlabArray);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    vector[i] = _isnan(data[i]) ? (T) (int) -9999 : (T) data[i];

// Clear temp variable
std::string clearTempVar = "clear " + tempName + "; ";
matlabExecute(ep, clearTempVar);

// Destroy mx object
mxDestroyArray(matlabArray);
```